# Custom complex loss function using the inputs of the model in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am now using tensorflow 2.12.0. I wish to create a custom loss function
to train my machine model with tensorflow. In this loss function I would have to use
the inputs and the outputs of my machine learning model and I am using a complex integral
calculation formula.

here is my custom loss function :

```
def custom_loss(y_pred, input_model):
    # Inputs
    alpha0 = y_pred[0]
    alpha1 = y_pred[1]
    nu1 = input_model[2]
    nu2 = input_model[3]
    er = input_model[4]
    fr = input_model[5]

    # output
    #return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1) + something with i...
    result_anis=diff_erad((nu1, nu2, alpha0, alpha1, er))
    result_erad=diff_anis((nu1, nu2, alpha0, alpha1, fr))
    
    return K.mean(K.square(result_anis)) + K.mean(K.square(result_erad))
```

where `diff_anis` and `diff_erad` are functions that contain operations such as if/else structures, summation/division/multiplication/summation of the inputs with numpy arrays, ... These two functions work well with numpy array elements.

Here is how I define the loss function before to train my neural network:

```
# Input layer
input_model = Input(shape=(4,))
x = Dense(6)(input_model)
    
# Hidden layer
x = Dense(6, activation="tanh")(x)
x = Dense(6, activation="tanh")(x)

# Output layer
output_model = Dense(2, activation="ReLU")(x)

# Assemble the model
model = Model(input_data, output_data, name='MLP')

model.add_loss(custom_loss(output_mod, input_mod))
```

I already get errors from the last line.

Here is the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gradureau/IA/tests/./test_alpha_archs.py", line 883, in <module>
    model.add_loss(custom_loss(output_mod, input_mod))
  File "/home/gradureau/IA/tests/./test_alpha_archs.py", line 826, in custom_loss
    result_anis=diff_erad((nu1, nu2, alpha0, alpha1, er))
  File "/home/gradureau/IA/tests/./test_alpha_archs.py", line 714, in <lambda>
    diff_erad = lambda X: tf.map_fn(lambda x: calc_erad(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3])-x[4], X, fn_output_signature=(tf.float32))
  File "/home/gradureau/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 648, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gradureau/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 576, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gradureau/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/map_fn.py", line 640, in map_fn_v2
    return map_fn(
  File "/home/gradureau/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 576, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gradureau/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/map_fn.py", line 385, in map_fn
    elems_flat_signature = [type_spec.type_spec_from_value(e) for e in elems_flat]
  File "/home/gradureau/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/map_fn.py", line 385, in <listcomp>
    elems_flat_signature = [type_spec.type_spec_from_value(e) for e in elems_flat]
  File "/home/gradureau/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/type_spec.py", line 958, in type_spec_from_value
    raise TypeError(f"Could not build a TypeSpec for {value} of "
TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(4,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='tf.__operators__.getitem_3/strided_slice:0', description="created by layer 'tf.__operators__.getitem_3'") of unsupported type <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>.
```

Is there a way to use my custom loss function without modifying it? Otherwise how must I adapt the functions `diff_erad` and `diff_anis` to use it as a loss function?

So far I have tried not modifying `diff_erad` and `diff_anis`, from what I could find on the internet unsuccessfully so.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to specify the error messages, we cannot guess them.